# Google Maps Location - Hide Blue dot (Current Location Marker) and Show My Location Button

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have an app with `Google Maps` with `custom marker` in my `location`. I'm trying my map showing the location button but not the blue dot. I've tried this but it not works:

`mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(false);`

`mapa.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);`

This code not shows button and blue dot. How I do?

Comment: try  map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

Comment: @IllegalArgument this not shows the button location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location button is only visible when the `My Location` layer is enabled with the `setMyLocationEnabled` method.  You can simulate this behavior by adding a similar button of your own that will center on the user's location when it is pressed.